# Crontab not running

Tags: php, cron

I've been having some issues with crontab recently. After switching servers, I realized none of my cronjobs are being run. After looking at PHP info, I realized php was run with CGI, so I realized I had to switch `lynx -dump URL_HERE` to `php -q PATH_HERE`.

In the actual PHP file, I stared it out like `#!/usr/bin/php -q` to define where php is located on my server. However, it's not getting run. I've even set up crontab to send me an email once anything runs. No email. I've checked my junk, trash, spam, and I've even tried switching emails. Nothing.

Here's what I have now: `* * * * * php -q /home/USER/public_html/file.php`.

If I copy & paste it into the command line, it works wonderfully. If I run it through crontab, it doesn't get run.

Comment: As which user did you run the command line?  And which user's crontab settings is that?

Comment: A user other than root.

Comment: And *crond* is running?

Comment: AFAIK, yes. How do you check?

Comment: I typed `crond` into the command line, and it said cron is now starting up. It works now. Wow, I'm dumb.

Comment: That happens to me too once in a while.  ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing envrionment variables.   Try a simple test like this

add this to your crontab

```
* * * * *  set > /tmp/vars
```

wait 2 -3 minutes, go back and remove the crontab entry you just created.

Next,

From the shell command line you normally use

```
set > myvars
diff myvars /tmp/vars
```

This will show you the differEnce in envIrionment.  Modify your cron job environment.  Just add what is needed.

Comment: When I put in the command in terminal, I got: `diff: /tmp/vars: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please. Post the EXACT output of this command: ls /tmp/vars      Did you wait for several minutes?  Did you use crontab -e and not vi?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a couple things in order to debug this.

1) In your crontab change your entry to:

```
* * * * * php -q /home/USER/public_html/file.php > /tmp/filecron 2>&1
```

Make sure you edit the entry by typing:

```
crontab -e
```

Then run:

```
tail -f /tmp/filecron
```

To debug the output as it runs.

2) As sudo user or root, tail the cron log to make sure your cron is executing properly:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/cron
```

The first step will give you information related to the php file itself (syntax errors etc) if that is what is failing. The second step will help you out if the crontab itself is not configured properly.

You are intending this job to run every 5 minutes right ? This is what it will do with your stated line.

Comment: When I SSH from root & try #2, I get a log of my edits of cron jobs, nothing where they are supposed to execute. When SSHing as a user, I get this error: `USER is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.` Oh, and eventually I want to run the script once a day at a certain time, but to test I've just been running it every minute.

Comment: Do you have root access to this machine? If so, you shouldn't add the "sudo" part of the command. I am sorry if that wasn't clear.